# Toggle multiple divs with one button

Tags: javascript, show-hide, increment

I´m trying to "toggle" multiple divs with just 2 buttons (one for **SHOW** and the other for **HIDE**) in relation to the last div showed by the function, with SHOW and HIDE

So, if I click one time (on SHOW), it must display div with class num1. If I click again, div with class num2 until num5. But, if I click on HIDE, it must hide the last div showed. Is this possible?

Comment: [*What should I do if no one answers my question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers).

Comment: Show us what you have tried please; perhaps we can then fix it? (code and markup/html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it like this:

Use an `index` to store the last class shown.

Everytime you click on the show button increment this `index` and then `$(".num"+index).show()` this class.

If you click the hide, do `$(".num"+index).hide()` and then decrement the `index`